# show UIMenuController in UITableViewCell, grouped style

Tags: uitableview, uimenucontroller

Is there a simple way to implement the copy menu when a cell is tapped, instead of subclassing the UITableViewCell?

thanks,

RL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes!
Call `[[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] setMenuVisible:YES animated:ani]` (where `ani` is a `BOOL` determining whether the controller should be animated) from within `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` ( UITableView's delegate method)

Edit: The 'copy' command on the `UIMenuController` will not by default copy the `detailTextLabel.text` text.  However, there is a workaround.  Add the following code into your class.

```
-(void)copy:(id)sender {
    [[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] setString:detailTextLabel.text];
}


- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
    if(action == @selector(copy:)) {
        return YES;
    }
    else {
        return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're putting it inside of `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, then the `UIMenuController` will come up when you select the row in an ordinary fashion (I gather that this is what you desire)

Comment: yes and no :) what i want is to get the menu, with the COPY option, to get the detailTextLabel.text text, like the Contacts App

Comment: Ah, that's a bit more complicated.  I'll update my answer to clarify.

Comment: Is it possible to use these delegate methods and show the menu controller on a single tap in didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Answer (score 10):

In iOS 5, a simple way is to implement the UITableViewDelegate Methods:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldShowMenuForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView performAction:(SEL)action forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath withSender:(id)sender 

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canPerformAction:(SEL)action forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath withSender:(id)sender
```

By implementing the 3 delegates, it will enable call UIMenuController for you after a long press gesture. An example like:

```
/**
 allow UIMenuController to display menu
 */
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldShowMenuForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}

/**
 allow only action copy
 */
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canPerformAction:(SEL)action forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath withSender:(id)sender 
{
    return action == @selector(copy:);
}

/**
 if copy action selected, set as cell detail text
 */
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView performAction:(SEL)action forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath withSender:(id)sender 
{
    if (action == @selector(copy:))
    {
        UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForIndexPath:indexPath];
        [[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] setString:cell.detailTextLabel.text];
    }
}
```