# How to enable UILabel such that user can long-press word to copy or "Define" it?

Tags: ios, iphone, uikit, uitextfield, uilabel

For example, if you have a multi line UILabel with text. By default the label is static and the user can't interact with it. User can't long press a word to look up definition or Wikipedia article for it.

At the same time you don't want that the user can edit it and you want it to look like a static piece of text. Must I use a UITextField instead? Or is there a way for UILabel that the user can look up words?

Comment: What you want to do on long press.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `UITextField` instead `UILabel` and in `UITextFieldDelegate` disable editing

Comment: ...and scrolling as well.

Comment: For text in a `UITableViewCell` you can check here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8664328/1049134